Word for Like-begging person
Can you tell me if there are informal or slang words for the one who begs for likes on the Internet?

I think 'like beggar' is what you want

Who cares about labeling the producer in terms of their motivation? All I care about is what they produce - clickbait, which I seek earnestly to avoid

So, @FumbleFingers, would someone flinging clickbait be a "clickbator" to coin a punmanteau?

@digimunk: No more than a person flinging bait would be a baitor, which I've never encountered. But a baiter would normally mean one who baits in the sense bait = torment, worry, rather than scatter / use enticement, allurement to capture prey. We don't seem to have an "agent" derivative of bait for the latter sense.

There isn't a widely used and accepted term for this in English.

Like Whore
Someone who pretty much begs for attention by posting Facebook statuses that appeal to as many people as possible for the sole purpose for getting a million "Likes."
Like Whore

Is this word commonly used? I’m not sure as I’m not a native speaker.

@user1176409 It's on urbandictionary.com, so someone somewhere is using it, and in any conversation in a social media context, any native speaker would not question the meaning if someone were to use the term.

@user1176409 - Definitions from the Urban Dictionary may not be understood by all groups.  If your audience is a younger, on-line crowd, they will easily understand what you are saying, especially if you've provided any context.  An older, offline crowd hearing this without context, might misinterpret the phrase, He is a like whore, to mean, He is like a whore,  which is an entirely different meaning.  If you're not sure if Urban Dictionary slang is appropriate, avoid using it.  You don't want to have to explain to people why you said someone was like a whore.  :)
